# Match array object with text of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects which all follow the same format and another array of objects

Using the following code, I am able to generate the subheadings with no issues. However what I would like to have is subheadings separating the generated services. The subheadings separations are based on the `services[k].category`.

This is what I have so far, however it is not working. The subheadings generate without issue, however the rest is not working:

```js
let categories = [{
    name: "Logo and Branding"
  },
  {
    name: "Web Design"
  },
  {
    name: "Print"
  },
  {
    name: "Presentations"
  },
  {
    name: "Art & Illustration"
  },
  {
    name: "Animation"
  }
]

let services = [{
  "name": "Logo",
  "description": "Capture the essence of your brand with an unforgettable logo design.",
  "icon": "logo.svg",
  "category": "logo"
}]

function generateServices(amount) {
  var content = "";

  for (let q = 0; q < categories.length; q++) {
    content += '<div class="col-12 main_titleCol"><div class="main_title"><h2 class="servicestitle">' + categories[q].name + '</h2></div></div>';
  }

  $('.services').html(content);

  let servicesheading = $('.servicestitle');
  // add the new items 
  for (let k = 0; k < amount; k++) {
    console.log(servicesheading.html);
    if (servicesheading.innerText == services[k].description) {
      content += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><div class="feature_item"><img class="img-fluid services-icon" src="img/services/SVG/' + services[k].icon + '"><h4>' + services[k].name + '</h4><p>' + services[k].description + '</p></div></div>';
    }
  }
}

generateServices(10)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services"></div>
```

The final outcome should look like this if all were to work:
[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: _"I have an array of objects...and the following code that generates them"_ - That "code" creates a string of markup and not a single object o.O

Comment: _"Would this be the right approach?"_ - Give it a try. If it works the answer would be "yes". If not make a [mcve] and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the question to better fit the requirements of StackOverflow and also show an example of my coding. Hope this is better.

Comment: @Andreas Gave it a try and showed my code. Hope it constitutes a MVP

Comment: I made you the snippet I asked you to make in my first comment

Comment: *"the rest is not working"*: that is not a very clear problem statement. Please provide the expected output for your runnable snippet, so it becomes clear what exactly "not working" means.

Comment: @trincot if you check out the snipper that mpl kindly made for me, you will see that the headings are being generated but not the rest of the content.

Comment: So what is "the rest of the content"? Can you provide in your question what the expected output should look like?

Comment: @trincot added an image of what the final outcome should look like.

Comment: I don't see how that image matches the data in your code. Where does "business card" (that I see in the desired output) come from? Where is "Print" (that I find in the code) represented in the image? Can you make a consistent input/desired output combo? Also in your sample input I see nothing that connects categories with services. There is not one property that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Let's group our initial array of services by category:**

```js
const services = [
  { name: '...', category: '...', 'description': '...', 'icon': '...' },
  { name: '...', category: '...', 'description': '...', 'icon': '...' },
  { name: '...', category: '...', 'description': '...', 'icon': '...' },
...
];
const servicesByCategory = services.reduce((acc,el) => {
  if (acc[el.category]) acc[el.category].push(el)
  else acc[el.category] = [el]; 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

`servicesByCategory` is an object where keys are service categories and values are arrays of services assigned to category:

```js
{
  service1: [ { name: '...', ... }, ... ],
  service2: [ { name: '...', ... }, ... ],
  service3: [ { name: '...', ... }, ... ],
  ...
}
```

**2. Now you can process services one by one for each category:**

```js
let content = '';
for (let category in servicesByCategory) {
  // Do what you want with category name
  // Let's add category header as an example 
  content += '<div class="col-12 main_titleCol"><div class="main_title"><h2 class="servicestitle">' + category + '</h2></div></div>';
  
  for (let service of servicesByCategory[category]) {
    // Proccess services one-by-one as you did before
    content += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><div class="feature_item"><img class="img-fluid services-icon" src="img/services/SVG/' + service.icon + '"><h4>' + service.name + '</h4><p>' + service.description +'</p></div></div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is going on in the 2nd block of code. I am failing to understand this one. What do I need to do with my categories array to achieve this?

Comment: @EGxo Its example of `servicesByCategory` structure. Try out provided code, and print out `servicesByCategory` value somewhere to see what I mean.

Comment: I played around with your code to try to figure it out and it all worked out great. I actually just saw your reply now after figuring it out on my own. This is an amazing solution, works wonderfully. Thank you for being so thorough in the explanation and helping me through this. Awesome work here +++